# Javascript: Need regex to split string into array, leaving decimal points and quotes intact

Tags: javascript, regex, match, quotes, decimal-point

I need to go from this:

```
myString = This "so called answer" is only 50.1% wrong!
```

To this:

```
myArray = ['This', '"so called answer"', 'is', 'only', '50.1%', 'wrong!']
```

I am using:

```
myArray = myString.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g);
```

I get:

```
['This', '"so called answer"', 'is', 'only', '50', '1%', 'wrong!']
```

I realize I need something else in my match expression to avoid splitting on the decimal point, but I have no idea what to add (or where).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Can you simply split on whitespace?

```js
const input = `This "answer" is only 50.1% wrong!`;
const output = input.split(/\s/);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Some of the expressions in quotes will have spaces in them. That's what led me to turn to match().

Answer (score 2):

The `\w` searches for alphanumeric characters (`A-Z,a-z,0-9`), so will not capture any period or other characters like that. I suggest looking for any non-space characters with `[^\s]`. Additionally, since you do not want to split spaces in quotes, you can add `^"` to the first group.

```
/[^\s"]+|"[^"]+"/g
```

Check the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/WsolrD/2)

Comment: This solved one problem and raised another: Now I get the decimal number in one piece, but if I have a quote-enclosed expression with spaces between multiple words, it splits that into multiple elements. The original expression avoided this problem.

Comment: @lot49 I noticed this just a few seconds ago and updated to address this!